# Unable to search in graylog

Tags: graylog

I am trying to figure why graylog displays this error in the search tab:

[image]

I tried searching the web for clues and this was the closest but it did not state the resolution: https://community.graylog.org/t/unable-to-perform-search-query-1-293-bool-unknown-field-disable-coord/16582. Could it be some misconfiguration?